# How can I use jQuery to select a child tag of every sibling?

Tags: jquery, children, siblings

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><div class="color">Stuff</div></td>
    <td><div class="color">Stuff</div></td>
    // etc.
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="color">Stuff</div></td>
    <td><div class="color">Stuff</div></td>
    // etc.
</tr>
```

Every `<td>` of any given row will be a certain color. When I click on a table cell I want to add a black border to the clicked `<td>`, and remove the black border from any cells in the clicked row (but not in other rows) that may already have the black border. How can I do this?

jQuery (doesn't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.color").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('black_border');
        $(this).addClass('black_border');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: div.color doesn't have any siblings. you need to do $(this).parents('tr').find("div.color').removeClass('black_border');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that (unless you've elected to `stopPropagation()`, or `return false` in your click-handlers) the click will bubble up to the `td` element, just target the `td` in your jQuery:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('black_border');
    $(this).addClass('black_border');
});
```

Or, a little differently:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.black_border').removeClass('black_border');
    $(this).addClass('black_border');
});
```

And, given that you're using `$(this)` more than once, it's worth caching that, rather than recreating the jQuery object each time:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.closest('tr').find('.black_border').removeClass('black_border');
    that.addClass('black_border');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').removeClass('black_border');
```

Answer (score 0):

$("div.color").on('click',function() {

```
var $td= $(this).parent();
$td.siblings('.black_border').removeClass('black_border');
$td.addClass('black_border');
```

});